# Separar textos por comillas y convertirlo en array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Hola tengo un texto de esta forma:

> 6. "Toyota Supra" 2. "Dodge Challenger" 5. "Ford Mustang" 4. "Dodge Charger" 3. "Chevrolet Camaro"

La idea es que los que estan entre comillas se separen en un arreglo para que queden así:

> ["Toyota Supra","Dodge Challenger","Ford Mustang","Dodge
> Charger","Chevrolet Camaro"]

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `preg_match_all($expr, $subject, &$matches)` ayuda a encontrar expresiones y devolverlas en un array (el segundo elemento del array resultante son las concidencias de la expresion entre parentesis (en este caso, lo que esta entre comillas `"`

```
$text = '"Toyota Supra" 2. "Dodge Challenger" 5. "Ford Mustang" 4. "Dodge Charger" 3. "Chevrolet Camaro"';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/',$text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Retornará en `$matches[1]`:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Toyota Supra,
  [1] => Dodge Challenger,
  [2] => Ford Mustang,
  [3] => Dodge Charger,
  [4] => Chevrolet Camaro 
)
```

Nota: La expresion regular `"([^"]+)"` busca todas las concidencias que esten entre comillas `"` y que a la vez no tenga comillas entre la expresion (`[^"]+`). De otra manera solo retornaria una gran expresion entre la primera y la ultima comilla `"Toyota Supra" 2. "Dodge Challenger" 5. "Ford Mustang" 4. "Dodge Charger" 3. "Chevrolet Camaro"`

Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Funciono perfecto, es justo lo que necesitaba!! Muchas gracias F.Igor